# JavaScript/jQuery query as mySQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, arrays, sorting

I have a SQL db and I use this to query the db:

> SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( latitude
>   ) ) * cos( radians( longitude ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) )
>   * sin( radians( latitude ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM stores HAVING distance < 12925 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;

The variables are be 37, -122 coordinates

I have this data as a SQL db, but I exported the db as an JavaScript array and I want to sort and get a new array that will contain only the results based on the query I used to do with mySQL, but this time I want to do-it only with JavaScript or jQuery.

I there any way to do this?

Edit - Is there any way to alter arrays based on complex queries with JavaScript?

Comment: `I exported the db as an JavaScript array`.. are you sure... cause javascirpt is client side and SQL is in server ...

Comment: So, you have your table data as a javascript array, is what you're saying? And you want to use javascript to pull the same results as you did with that sql query? Have you tried anything at all yet?

Comment: @bipen Yes, I did this with json_encode.

Comment: @Yatrix - No, I did not, I think there is a way with jQuery .map() or .grep() but the question is if there is a way to do such complex query.

Comment: can you give us examples since it is hard to get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any way to do this automagically (in SQL-like fashion), but you could try something like the following (see comments in code):

Live example **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/sGpfH/)**.

```
/* Declare utility function to convert degrees to radians */
function radians(deg) {
    return deg * Math.PI / 180;
}

/* Declare utility function to compute distance from (37, -122) */
/* (If these values change dynamically they should */
/* be given as parameters to the function.) */
var cos37 = Math.cos(radians(37));
var sin37 = Math.sin(radians(37));
function distance(lat, long) {
    var dist = 3959 
               * Math.acos(cos37
                               * Math.cos(radians(lat))
                               * Math.cos(radians(long) 
                                          - radians(-122))
                           + sin37 
                               * Math.sin(radians(lat)));
    return dist;
}

/* Somehow populate a 2-dimensional array containing all entries. */
/* Each row should look like this: [id, latitude, longtitude] */
var allArr = ...;     // [[id1, lattitude1, longtitude1],[id2, lattitude2, longtitude2],...]

/* Populate a new array containing [id, distance] of those entries */
/* whose distance from (37, -122) is less than 12925. */
var newArr = [];
for (var i = 0; i < allArr.length; i++) {    
    var dist = distance(allArr[i][1]/*latitude*/, 
                        allArr[i][2]/*longtitude*/);
    if (dist < 12925) {
        newArr.push([allArr[i][0]/*id*/, 
                     dist]);
    }
}
```

I also noticed that it is impossible to find any two places on earth with a distance greater than 12925 miles, so unless you are designing some extraterestrial web-app, you might want to revise your specs :)

Comment: Thank you for the effort, you are a genius! :D